# Is there a simpler single polygon toroid?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, polygons, polyhedra, solid-geometry

In B.M. Stewart's book [Adventures Among the Toroids](http://polyhedra.doskey.com/Stewart00.html), [toroidal shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_polyhedron) of many sorts are made.  One of them is the ring of 8 octahedra, with 48 faces.  The toroid is made with a single polygon -- the equilateral triangle.

[image: ring of 8 octahedra]

Are there single non-regular polygons that can make a toroidal shape with fewer than 48 faces?  One restriction -- all neighboring polygons must be in different planes, to prevent things like the ring of 8 cubes.

The faces should be non-intersecting.  The underlying graph of edges might be one of these, maybe.

[image: transitive graphs]

Comment: Am I looking at it wrongly, or does the second example graph have some faces which are triangles and some which are quadrilaterals?

Answer (score 5):

Let $y=2, x=\sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{2}}\approx 2.79793 $, Then the following toroid with green $y$ and blue $x$ lengths is made from 24 identical triangles. But there may be something smaller.

[image: toroid24]

Took less than 12 hours for [someone](http://robertfathauer.com/) to build it.

[image: toroid24 paper]

The net, with green points the 6 outer vertices:
[image: Toroid net]

Is there anything smaller than 24 faces?  Here's something larger.

Let $y=2, -127 + 124 x^2 - 26 x^4 - 4 x^6 + x^8=0, x\approx 2.31498614558$.  Then the following toroid with green $y$ and blue $x$ lengths is made from 32 identical triangles.

[image]