# Triangular grids on a torus

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

## Definitions

The *torus* that we consider is the flat representation given by the quotient $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$, or equivalently as the set
$$
\tau = \{\, (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : 0 \leq x, y \leq 1 \,\}
$$
with the points $(x, y), (x+1, y), (x, y+1)$ identified. The 3D torus is not of interest here.

Consider the torus as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then a *line* is what we would usually consider a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, with the identification of edges possibly splitting the line into many segments bounded by the boundary of the torus. For example, the following (left) image is the line of gradient $4/3$ on the torus that passes through $(0,0)$. The right image is twelve tilings of the flat representation to show where each segment on the left comes from.

[image]

A *partitioning of the torus* is an arrangement of lines on the torus. These lines must extend from boundary to boundary, as above.

A *triangular grid* is a partitioning of the torus by **three sets of parallel lines** such that every vertex has degree $6$ and every face is a triangle. We may assume the lines to be horizontal, vertical, and of a rational slope if necessary. One example of a triangular grid is given below, followed by five partitions that are allowed on the torus.

[image]
[image]

It is important that there are exactly **three distinct gradients** that the lines can have, and that the **lines continue from boundary to boundary**. For example, the flat representation of the {"Circulant", {9, {1, 2, 3}}} graph (taken from [Ed Pegg's answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2884116/350028)) does not fit the requirements of a triangular grid as the lines do not have exactly three different gradients. This is not an allowed partition either as not all lines extend from boundary to boundary.

[image]

## Useful Identities

Let every intersection of lines induce a vertex, let each line segment between connected vertices be an edge, and let the closed interior of at least two incident edges be a face. Let $V, E, F$ be the number of vertices, edges, and faces that the torus is partitioned into, respectively. It is well known that the Euler characteristic of the torus is zero, so
$$
V - E + F = 0.\tag{1}
$$
Let $d(v)$ denote the degree of the vertex $v$ (which must be even, by construction). It is also well known that summing the degrees of all vertices gives
$$
2E = \sum d(v).\tag{2}
$$
Let $F_{s}$ denote the number of faces with $s > 1$ edges. When there are no loops in the graph, a simple counting argument shows that
$$
2E = \sum_{s \geq 2} sF_{s}.\tag{3}
$$
It is also trivial that $F = \sum_{s \geq 2} F_{s}$.

## Lemma -- Question

We start with a simple lemma:

> **Lemma.** Consider a partitioning of the torus into $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and $F$ faces that form a triangular grid. Then
>   $$
> E = 3V \qquad\text{and}\qquad F = 2V.
> $$

*Proof.* Every face has $3$ edges, so $F = F_{3}$. By $(3)$, we have
$$
2E = \sum_{s\geq 2}sF_{s} = 3F_{3} = 3F.
$$
By $(1)$, we have $V - E + F = 0$ so that $3F - 3E = -3V$. We have a system of simultaneous equations, namely
$$
3F - 2E = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 3F - 3E = -3V.
$$
Solving this gives $E = 3V$ and $F = 2V$ as required.$\qquad\square$

My question is the following.

> Is the converse of the Lemma true? That is, if some partitioning of the torus has $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and $F$ faces such that $E = 3V$ and $F = 2V$, then is it true that the partition is necessarily a triangular grid?

I have not yet been able to find a counter-example. In the proof of the converse, I want to prove that $d(v) = 6$ for all vertices $v$, and that $F_{3} = F$ with $F_{i} = 0$ for all $i \neq 3$.

I have noticed that we cannot have any faces with more than $6$ edges so that the $s$ index only runs between $2$ and $6$, but there still seem to be too many variables to do anything (namely, each of the vertex degrees and the five $F_{s}$ for $s \in [2, 6]\cap\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEW:  Up to 20 vertices, [all sextic toroidal graphs can be represented as triangular grids](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SexticToroidalGraphs/).

NEW:  Consider the following toroidal graph:
[image: toroidal 12]
In a triangular grid embedding each of the 6 spokes connects to the opposing spoke. if you follow a path with this graph you end up with the path crossing itself. Therefore it is not a triangular grid.

My torus from [Is there a simpler single polygon toroid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864935/) has 12 vertices, 24 faces, 36 edges, meeting the criteria.  But the vertices have valence 5 and 7, which is impossible for a triangular grid. The converse of the lemma is false.

[image: single triangle torus]

The ring of 8 octahedra, with 24 vertices, 48 faces, 72 edges is another counterexample. Some of the valences are 8, impossible for a triangular grid.

[image: ring of 8 octahedra]

Make the question a bit friendlier.

> Is there a toroidal sextic graph which is not a triangular grid?

$K_7$ is a toroidal grid.  The grid has a signature of $(1,1,1)$.  This is the number of lines in each parallel class. Also the $7_{1,2,3}$ [circulant graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html).

[image: K7]

The 16-cell graph is a triangular grid graph. The grid has a signature of $(1,1,2)$. Also the $8_{1,2,3}$ [circulant graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html).

[image: 16-cell]

The {"CompleteTripartite", {3, 3, 3}} graph is a triangular grid graph.  The grid has a signature of $(3,3,3)$.  Also the $9_{1,2,4}$ [circulant graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html).

[image]

The {"Circulant", {9, {1, 2, 3}}} graph is a triangular grid graph.  The grid has a signature of $(1,1,3)$.

[image]

The other two 9-vertex [sextic graphs may not be toroidal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884858/).

The Paley 13 graph is toroidal on a triangular grid.  Notice that edge differences are all in $(1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12)$, the values that are squares in $GF(13)$.  The grid has a signature of $(1,1,1)$. Also the $13_{1,3,4}$ [circulant graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html).

[image: Paley 13]

All of the grids so far have been circulant graphs, which suggests a construction method for these triangular grids. Here are the distinct sextic circulant graphs up to 17 vertices.

[image: circulant values]

Above, for 7,8,9 vertices we have a sequence that starts 1,1,2.  That seems to be sequence [A129033](http://oeis.org/A129033). $(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, ...)$.  That matches [surftri counts](http://hep.physics.indiana.edu/~tsulanke/graphs/surftri/counts.txt), also mentioned at [Generating Triangulations](http://hep.physics.indiana.edu/~tsulanke/graphs/surftri/).

Not all triangular grid graphs are circulant, with the [Shrikhande graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrikhande_graph) being one example.

Sextic triangular toroidal graphs don't have a combinatorial explosion. It seems worthwhile to completely classify the circulant and Shrikhande-like cases beyond 17 vertices for [A129033](http://oeis.org/A129033).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your faces are polygons, with at least three edges. Each face has
at least three edges, and each edge must be in exactly two faces. Thus
$2E\ge 3F$ with equality iff each edge is a triangle. So your conditions
force every face to be a triangle.

Now the question is what is a "triangular grid"? The minimum triangulation
of a torus has $14$ faces and looks, at least to me, nothing like a grid.
And in the grid you've drawn, you can take a pair of adjacent triangles,
merge them into a quadrilateral, and then split the quadrilateral into
triangles in the "other way". Doing this repeatedly will disrupt the
apparent grid structure.

Comment: For my purposes, a _triangular grid_ is the grid obtained by arranging three sets of parallel lines so that each vertex has a degree of $6$ (much like [isometric graph paper](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=isometric+line+paper&hl=en-GB&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitifbX9-_cAhVDI8AKHXhhBy0Q_AUICigB&biw=1517&bih=701) and any affine transform of it). By taking two sets to be horizonal and vertical, we can enclose an area by a square and identify edges to get the torus and grid I described above. I imagine that this triangulation is different to any triangulation in the literature.

Comment: The important thing is that there are exactly three direction/gradients that any line can have. This excludes the disruption you propose (I hope).

Comment: This answer turns out to be wrong, $K_7$ on a torus does correspond to a triangular grid.

Comment: @BillWallis: Your last comment does not exclude this answer. Your question asks: "If some partitioning of the torus has $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and $F$ faces such that $E = 3V$ and $F = 2V$, then is it true that the partition is necessarily a triangular grid?" and the construction in this question shows that the answer is "no". Your question did not contain any requirements about "lines". In fact, in the context of a partitioning that satisfies the hypotheses of your question, I'm not even sure what one might mean by "lines".

Comment: @LeeMosher Actually, the way that I defined triangular grids in the second paragraph of the post intended to show the requirement about lines, and confirmed that a line is _straight_ if it is straight on the flat representation. The 3D case is not important for my purposes. I agree that there is some ambiguity about what a _line_ is and how exactly the triangular grids may be constructed, so I shall edit the question.

Comment: The definition of a triangular grid is not the issue. The issue is the overall logic of your post and of this answer. As written your post asks this question: Is a partition of the torus satisfying certain requirements on $V,E,F$ necessarily a triangular grid? And the answer is: No, here is a partition satisfying those requirements that is not a triangular grid.

Comment: @LeeMosher Ah, of course, my apologies. I did not make it clear that the _partitioning itself_ has certain requirements. This is indeed a partitioning that satisfies the requirements in its current formulation.