# Is there a 40 face single polygon toroid?

Tags: polyhedra

Solutions for 24 and 32 face single polygon toroid have been given.  Is there a solution for the next step of a 40 face single polygon toroid?

[Is there a simpler single polygon toroid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864935/is-there-a-simpler-single-polygon-toroid)

The opening on the 24 face toroid is an equilateral triangle.  The opening on the 32 face toroid is a regular square.  It seems there should be a 40 face single polygon toroid with a regular pentagonal opening.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you having your difficulties?  Have you solved it for any other number of faces?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have constructed the 24 and 32 face toroid out of paper.  Those made me think there was a solution to a 40 face toroid (maybe even a 48 face toroid that is not a Stewart Toroid).  I don't have the math skills to solve the question I have asked.

Comment: @EricJordan: You should [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3264792/edit) to add the clarifying context. Comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search with the title of this post brings up this very post on first place and a solution with 48 triangles on [the second](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/21_2864935/is-there-a-simpler-single-polygon-toroid/).

--- rk

Comment: QueryXchange (the target of your link) is a site-scraper. A better target is Ed Pegg's original post, right here on Math.SE: ["Is there a simpler single polygon toroid?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2864935/409) (which has actual answers).